# Angular components using jquery not rendering due to suspected file error

Tags: jquery, angular, asynchronous, rendering

I am very new to learning about rendering and new to Jquery, and there seems to be a very odd issue in my Angular application. The problem on a high level is that whenever I reroute a component using `routerlink`, the components that use jquery tend to disappear OR when I asynchronously use `ActivateChild` to load a component, all the jquery components just stop working  By disappear, I mean the container has `display: none` so I would *assume* that this is the jquery not working. Please take a look at my root index.html folder.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Fitness Hub</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="./assets/assets/favicon/Frame 3.svg">

   <!--A bunch of CSS files that I believe are irrelvent. -->
  
  
   
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>


    <!--All Js Here-->
    <!-- jquery latest version (note: I first used jquery in node_modules and 
it give me MIME type ("text") is not executable. 
I changed to use the CDN and I am not getting the error in console 
but I am still not seeing my components.) -->
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-eKhayi8LEQwp4NKxN+CfCh+3qOVUtJn3QNZ0TciWLP4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 

    <!--Other JS files ...-->
   
    <!-- template main js file -->
    <script src="./assets/assets/js/main.js"></script>
</html>
```

Please take a look at the following images to further understand what I mean

[image: Notice how the slider ..exists]

Now when I typed "7636668" in the URL, activateChild is an async function and will be called. This allows me to go to the URL and then go to the link. However, as you see, the slider *that uses jQuery* is gone.

[image: Notice the slider is gone!!!]

There are also other components that disappeared (again, that uses Jquery)), but I would assume you get the idea.

I'll also show you my async activateChildFn in my Routing Module.

```js
  const canActivateChild: CanActivateChildFn = (route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) => {
    let authenticated = new Promise<boolean>((resolve, rej) => {
      inject(HttpClient).get('{{// my API endpoint}}').subscribe((res) => {
        if (res.hasOwnProperty(route.params['id'])) {
          resolve(true)
        }
        else {
          resolve(false)
        }
     })
    })
  
    return authenticated // notice a promise is being returned!!!
   
  
    }
```

Now that you know my root HTML, what I was getting in the console, and my `canActivateChild` function, I hope this is enough information to solve the problem. If you have any inquries regarding my code, then I am here.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: you should really axe jQuery altogether and use Angular to do what jQuery used to do.  Otherwise you'll have angular and jquery trying to do things the other isn't aware of.   (they'll both try to bind/handle events...)

Comment: @pcalkins I wish I could do that, but I'll need to write a new code base which is gonna be costy :(

Comment: You probably want to include your jQuery code and any errors that appear in dev console.  Make sure you are using .on to trigger functions from events.  Then check the event for source and case/switch from there.  Some things my also need to be triggered on hash change.